# Insight regarding the existence of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the infimum of the set is greater than the supremum of the set

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking through a book of counterexamples in analysis, "Counterexamples in Analysis and Probability," and I found the following:

> There exists a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the infimum of the set
>   is greater than the supremum of the set.

I was hoping to get some insight on this set and how to think of it. The book did not elaborate further and I can not make sense of how such a set exists and what its properties must be.

Is there a constructive proof of this, or do we only know its existence? Is it using some axiom of choice strangeness?

Comment: Take the emptyset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is non-empty, say $a \in A$, then we have by the definition of supremum and infimum, that $\inf A \le a \le \sup A$, hence by transitivity, $\inf A \le \sup A$.

On the other hand, every real number is an upper and lower bound for $\emptyset$, so if you allow $\pm \infty$ as supremum and infimum, the greatest lower bound of $\emptyset$ is $\inf\emptyset = +\infty$, and the smallest upper bound is $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$.